# Java - JUnit Test Generators

Tags: java, testing, junit4

I would like to know about good tools to automatically generate JUnit4 tests. By automatic generation, I mean that if I write a .java file, then a test file for the same should be created with method placeholders and setup/teardown in place (like the auto-generate constructors feature of eclipse)

I found some but I haven't tried them all and frankly I am overwhelmed by the plethora of choices. I was wondering if someone has tried some/all of them and has any recommendations from these or any other.

- http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/junitgenerator/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/junittestmaker/
- http://jub.sourceforge.net/
- http://testcasegen.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/JUnit-Test-Generator.shtml
- http://mediakey.dk/~cc/generate-junit-tests/
- http://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/junit/test_case_generation?hl=hu-HU
- http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/fit/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the Eclipse plugin  [**MoreUnit**](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/). It can generate TestClasses and test-methods. It also shows which methods have test methods ...

Together with **TestNG**(JUnit is also good) and **EclEmma** junit testing is quite easy to handle and keep track on the code coverage

Comment: MoreUnit is a promising tool. However, here I still have to generate tests manually by clicking on each method stub. I was wondering if there is a batch processor for what MoreUnit is doing. So that I can write all the code I want, then batch process it to generate test stubs and then fill out the tests later.

Comment: Actually I already have some code without much test code in place. So instead of clicking each method, I was looking for a batch processor.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions: [Randoop](https://code.google.com/p/randoop/), [AgitarOne](http://www.agitar.com/solutions/products/automated_junit_generation.html), and [EvoSuit](http://www.evosuite.org/downloads/) for Java.

Comment: I had high hopes for Randoop from the command line but found it tricky to use.

Answer (score 4):

The **[Squaretest](https://squaretest.com/)** plugin for IntelliJ IDEA works well. It can auto-generate test-classes with a lot of the required boilerplate code. It supports creating tests in either Java or Groovy with the JUnit4, JUnit5, AndroidJUnit4 or Robolectric3 test frameworks.

*Disclaimer*: I created the Squaretest plugin.

Answer (score 3):

[CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro) Plugin for Eclipse is also good. Exiting thing for me is it generates multipe testcases covering all the execution paths of a method, analyses dead code and dependencies and has lot of other features.
Check out the [User Guide](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) here

Comment: Indeed. It does a lot more than just checking coverage.

Comment: Hasn't been updated for latest eclipse versions.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is [JUnit-Tools](http://www.junit-tools.org) to generate JUnit Tests and more. It's a eclipse plug-in and up to date. Further there are many possibilities to configure and to adapt.